# My python version in windows command prompt is different than anaconda prompt

Tags: python

In windows command prompt, my python version is 2.6.5 but in my anaconda prompt, my python version is 3.6.8. How can I update my python version in windows command prompt?

Answer (score 2):

In Windows to change you're python version you need to change you're path and in order to do that you need to go to Edit the System Environment Variables -> Click Environment Variables and then append the Path variable with the path of python (something like C:\Anaconda3; in your case) that should make it so you run that version of python.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I added C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3 to the Environment Variables but still when typing python on wincows command prompt, it sais python 2.x!

Comment: Also add C:\python36 to the env variables and it should be good. Adding that python 3.6 path will ensure python3 is default